Congratulations user3306356 on your third Socratic badge!
The gold Socratic badge:

Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

And I just noticed that user3306356 now has three.  !  In total, this requires at least 300 positive-score questions.
Soooo....
ℂ!!!  ●‿●

Thanks! I didn't even notice. 
Too bad it didn't happen during hats day, then I would have gotten a Foot of the Rainbow.
